# I cant get the references correct for my document. Caption and label are in the correct order

Tags: latex

So i cant get the references correct in my latex document. I've read about caption and label being in the correct order and i already have that. below are is a working document.tex with the error.

I'm still using a local file, because i dont know how to fix that. But it is just a random png image on my machine and that is working

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{report}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{ebgaramond}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

% Translation for references to objects
\makeatletter
\def\HyLang@dutch{%
\def\equationautorefname{Vergelijking}%
\def\footnoteautorefname{voetnoot}%
\def\itemautorefname{item}%
\def\figureautorefname{Figuur}%
\def\tableautorefname{Tabel}%
\def\partautorefname{Deel}%
\def\appendixautorefname{Bijlage}%
\def\chapterautorefname{hoofdstuk}%
\def\sectionautorefname{sectie}%
\def\subsectionautorefname{subsectie}%
\def\subsubsectionautorefname{subsubsectie}%
\def\paragraphautorefname{paragraaf}%
\def\subparagraphautorefname{subparagraaf}%
\def\FancyVerbLineautorefname{lijn}%
\def\theoremautorefname{Stelling}%
\def\pageautorefname{pagina}%
}
\g@addto@macro\extrasdutch\HyLang@dutch
\makeatother

\addto\captionsdutch{%
\renewcommand{\appendixname}%
{Bijlage}%
}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

% Table format
\pgfplotstableset{
every head row/.style={
before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={
after row=\bottomrule},
col sep = comma,
string type,
}

% Colors
\definecolor{title-color}{HTML}{4230b8}

% Title formats with custom coloring
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\bfseries\Huge\color{title-color}}{\thechapter.}{10pt}{}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{title-color}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{title-color}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{title-color}}

% No page number on TOC page 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Planning}
\label{chap:schedule}
First ref to figure \autoref{fig:schedule}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Planning}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/schedule.png}
    \label{fig:schedule}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

```
First ref to figure Figuur 1.1
    Figuur 1.1: Planning
```

It should be figure 1 instead of figure 1.1

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that allows us to reproduce your problem without access to your local files that you include?

Comment: yes will do, give me a second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `chngcntr` package to use `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twocolumn]{report}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{ebgaramond}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

% Translation for references to objects
\makeatletter
\def\HyLang@dutch{%
\def\equationautorefname{Vergelijking}%
\def\footnoteautorefname{voetnoot}%
\def\itemautorefname{item}%
\def\figureautorefname{Figuur}%
\def\tableautorefname{Tabel}%
\def\partautorefname{Deel}%
\def\appendixautorefname{Bijlage}%
\def\chapterautorefname{hoofdstuk}%
\def\sectionautorefname{sectie}%
\def\subsectionautorefname{subsectie}%
\def\subsubsectionautorefname{subsubsectie}%
\def\paragraphautorefname{paragraaf}%
\def\subparagraphautorefname{subparagraaf}%
\def\FancyVerbLineautorefname{lijn}%
\def\theoremautorefname{Stelling}%
\def\pageautorefname{pagina}%
}
\g@addto@macro\extrasdutch\HyLang@dutch
\makeatother

\addto\captionsdutch{%
\renewcommand{\appendixname}%
{Bijlage}%
}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

% Table format
\pgfplotstableset{
every head row/.style={
before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={
after row=\bottomrule},
col sep = comma,
string type,
}

% Colors
\definecolor{title-color}{HTML}{4230b8}

% Title formats with custom coloring
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\normalfont\bfseries\Huge\color{title-color}}{\thechapter.}{10pt}{}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{title-color}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{title-color}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{title-color}}

% No page number on TOC page 
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Planning}
\label{chap:schedule}
First ref to figure \autoref{fig:schedule}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Planning}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \label{fig:schedule}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for the first figure, but if I add a second one after that, that one also will be 1 instead of 2

Comment: nevermind, it is working